# Incompatible types in assignment. C

Tags: c, loops, types, incompatibletypeerror

This part of my code:

```
    char MAC_ADRESSES[MAX_LINES][100];
    for(j=i+1; j<=countlines; j++)
        {
            if((MAC_ADRESSES[j])==(MAC_ADRESSES[i]))
            {
                MAC_ADRESSES[j] = NULL;
            }
```

At the point where I want to change the string with a NULL I have a compiler error about incompatible types assignment. Do not understand why..

Comment: What's the definition of `MAC_ADRESSES`?

Comment: English is not a context-free language. "mistake" is a synonym for "error" but a "compiler mistake" is not the same as a "compiler error".

Comment: Sorry I edited it. Yes I've got a compiler error.
**char MAC_ADRESSES[MAX_LINES][100]**

Comment: Why you are not using `MAC_ADRESSES[j] = '0'` ?

Comment: Since the error message is about incompatible types, why did you think that telling us the type of MAC_ADRESSES (sic) would be irrelevant to figuring out the cause of the problem?

Comment: I comparing lines of an array. And if they are the same I just want to print it once.

Comment: MAC_ADRESSES[j] is 100 chars long, NULL is not ... seems obviously incompatible to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably `MAC_ADRESSES` is not an array of pointers.  `NULL` *is* a pointer (normally `(void *)0` in C), so you can't assign it to a non-pointer variable.

Edit:  Since your definition is `char MAC_ADRESSES[MAX_LINES][100]`, you have a 2D array, not an array of pointers.  You can't store `NULL` in this array.  You can wipe out a string by putting a null character in the first byte, though:

```
            MAC_ADRESSES[j][0] = '\0';
```

Note that you can't test strings for equality using `==`, either.  You should be using `strcmp`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `NULL` use `'\0'`

`NULL` is macros defined as

`#define NULL (void *)0`

or

`#define NULL 0` , hence the

`warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast`

As per your **edited** question use:

`MAC_ADRESSES[j][0] = '\0';`

Comment: because you're trying to assign a value to an array, as Carl Norum points out.

Comment: @same `error` ? If you've `char MAC_ADRESSES[MAX_LINES][100]`
Obviously `MAC_ADRESSES[j] = NULL;` is not valid use `MAC_ADRESSES[j][0] = '\0';`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this

```
for(j=i+1; j<=countlines; j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(MAC_ADRESSES[j],MAC_ADRESSES[i]) == 0)
        {
            MAC_ADRESSES[j][0] = 0;
        }
    }
```

Given that

```
char MAC_ADRESSES[MAX_LINES][100]
```

As I guess you are trying to remove duplicates

**BTW** `MAC_ADDRESS[j]` is an array - not a pointer! Hence `==` operator will not make any sense

Answer (score 1):

NULL is defined something like below

```
#define NULL (void*)0
```

So you can't assign void* type to char[][].(both are incompatible types)

If you want to invalidate use '\0' or 0;

```
MAC_ADRESSES[j][0] = '\0';

      (or)

MAC_ADRESSES[j][0] = 0;
```

(Note: Also you should use **strcmp / stricmp / strcasecmp** to compare the c string & == is not allowed on array bases)

Answer (score 0):

if `MAC_ADRESSES` isn't a pointer array then `MAC_ADRESSES[j] = NULL;` is wrong because `NULL` is a pointer and `MAC_ADRESSES` is not